# What does Remy mean

Tags: house-of-cards

In House of Cards S0108, when Francis was having a party to celebrate library constitution, Claire was sitting at bar alone, and Remy came to say hello. And this is their conversation:

Claire: "You wanna sit down and have a drink?"

Remy: "They booked me the bridal suite, There is champagne on ice..."

Claire: "My, my, you've grown very confident since you worked for Francis."

What does Remy mean here? It seems like what he say is kind of bold?

Answer (score 1):

There's no misinterpretation. He's inviting her to his luxury hotel room. The bridal suite is just another variant of "penthouse". "Champagne on ice" is literally that - something couples arrange to have in their hotel room for a romantic night.

The entire conversation starts off as petty flirting. But then you can tell at the end of the conversation when Remy says:

> "end of the hallway... in case you change your mind"

That he is seriously propositioning Claire to come to his room to sleep with him.

It's been a while since I watched through House of Cards. But my guess is that Remy knows Frank and Claire have an open marriage. He likely was bold enough to try his luck.